# how to close existing kafka producer

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.7-RELEASE and writing a producer. I'm reading documentation from here says as below.

"Starting with version 2.5, each of these extends KafkaResourceFactory. This allows changing the bootstrap servers at runtime by adding a Supplier to their configuration: setBootstrapServersSupplier(() → …​). This will be called for all new connections to get the list of servers. Consumers and Producers are generally long-lived. To close existing Producers, call reset() on the DefaultKafkaProducerFactory. To close existing Consumers, call stop() (and then start()) on the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry and/or stop() and start() on any other listener container beans"

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#connecting

Now, my question is

1. When and how should we call this reset method?
2. How do we handle it if we are using an older version of spring-kafka like 2.2.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Whenever you want to connect to the different broker; simply call `reset()` on the factory.
2. It is not possible with older versions, you have to create a new factory and template.